# Expandable UITableView Dynamic

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using [This Example](https://github.com/jozsef-vesza/TableViewExpansions) for Dynamically Expand Cells. This example shows how to expand cell using a data Model. but what i need is , when a cell clicks , it fetches the number of records to be expanded. i have tried to do as follows. but i can not achive what i wanted. Please some one help me with this.

this is how i dynamically add sample data to my Datamodel.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    DataModel.sampleDetails = ["Sample 1","sample 2","sample 3"]

    //historyTable.beginUpdates()

    switch expandedIndex {
    case .None:
        expandedIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row + 1, inSection: indexPath.section)

    case .Some(let index) where index.row == indexPath.row:
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)

    case .Some(let index) where index.row == indexPath.row + 1:
        expandedIndex = nil
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)

    case .Some(let index) where index.row < indexPath.row:
        expandedIndex = nil
        self.tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: max(0,indexPath.row - 1), inSection: indexPath.section))
    default:
        expandedIndex = nil
        expandedIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row + 1, inSection: indexPath.section)
    }

    //historyTable.endUpdates()
}
```

this is how i get the count of records for tableview

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let sample = !(DataModel.sampleDetails.isEmpty) ? DataModel.sampleDetails.count : 0

    return expandedIndex != nil ?
        viewModel.count() + sample :
        viewModel.count()
}
```

this works only if i change the code like below

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let sample = !(DataModel.sampleDetails.isEmpty) ? DataModel.sampleDetails.count : 0

    return expandedIndex != nil ?
        viewModel.count() + 1 :
        viewModel.count()
}
```

i dont know what is the issue.

Please help me

Comment: What's the error did you get ?

Comment: @ChathurangaSilva  This is what i get when i change the way of getting count

NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: @Darshana here is the answer,
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31200769/2273094
hope it will help you...

Comment: @Darshana added the simple Project in the link https://docs.zoho.com/file/uwwu487739e6616ae4289b18605a61df832f2

Comment: Sample Video of the application https://docs.zoho.com/file/uwwu45d66f14e9bdd47cebd2a71c951855ab0

Comment: @KoushikGounder thank you koshik i will give a try.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You've set dataModel.sampleDetails on didSelectRow.

```
 DataModel.sampleDetails = ["Sample 1","sample 2","sample 3"]
```

But

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { }
```

is called before you are setting the DataModel.sampleDetails. So you should put that line on viewDidLoad(). This will fix your problem

Comment: what i want to achive is , expand the table view only when a cell selected. and the table should know the number of records to be expand only when the cell selected. because i get the data by using a API.. thats where i got stuck :(

Comment: hmmm, so numbers of rows will get by API call ? This will lead for an animation lag

Comment: how can i achive this ? please help me

Comment: Try reloading the tableviewCell when you get the Data from the API. This would made a call back to `numberOfRowsInSection ` . Hopefully this may work for you.